# How to programatically select an item in a Flex List after dataProvider is updated?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, events, list

As I am somewhat new to Flex I may be missing something fundamental here.  I have a Spark List container whose dataProvider is bound to a result set coming back from a RemoteObject call.  Pretty standard stuff.

```
<s:List id="list" dataProvider="{model.stuff}" width="100%" height="100%"
        selectedIndex="@{selectedSlider.value}"
        itemRenderer="{stuffRenderer}">

</s:List>
```

The selectedIndex is associated with an HSlider, but that is not the problem.  My issue is that I would like to automatically select a certain "preferred" element from the list (only initially...to guide the user).

I tried to do that in a creationComplete event but my data hadn't shown up yet...setting `selectedIndex` didn't work...it was too early.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private function findAllUsers_resultHandler(e:ResultEvent):void
{
    list.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(e.result as Array);
    if(firstTry)
    {
        list.selectedIndex = 0;
        firstTry = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work, except my model layer has no knowledge of any views.  However, it did give me the idea to create a custom model changed event in my model layer and a custom listener in my view.  Tried this and it Just Works.

Comment: Yes indeed. If I were you, I would have a look at the Cairngorm Observer lib tp handle things like that

Answer (score 2):

`spark.components.List` has `spark.components.SkinnableDataContainer` in its class hierarchy which dispatches a `dataProviderChanged` event whenever the dataProvider changes. Unfortunatly there is no `[Event]` metadata in `SkinnableDataContainer` that allows using this event in MXML. So, you'll need to create your own custom component that extends `List`.

```
package
{
    import spark.components.List;

    [Event(name="dataProviderChanged", type="flash.events.Event")]
    public class MyList extends List
    {
        public function MyList()
        {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

By using your custom component you can add an event listener for `dataProviderChanged` and update your `selectedIndex` accordingly.

```
<ns1:MyList id="list" dataProvider="{model.stuff}" width="100%" height="100%"
        dataProviderChanged="selectedIndex = selectedSlider.value"
        selectedIndex="@{selectedSlider.value}"
        itemRenderer="{stuffRenderer}">
</ns1:MyList>
```

BTW: This works with other `List`-based components (like `DropDownList`) too.

Comment: Undoubtedly this would work...but am looking for a simpler solution involving events.

Comment: Well, if you don't need the MXML support you could add the event listener by ActionScript. Then you won't need a custom component. Of course, your event based solution is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should work if you just set the initial value of the slider to the index you want to be selected at the beginning.
Something like this:

```
<s:List dataProvider="{yourData}" selectedIndex="{hSlider.value}" /> <s:HSlider id="hSlider" minimum="0" maximum="{yourData.length - 1}" stepSize="1" value="theIndexYouWantAsInitial" liveDragging="true" />
```

That should work.
HTH
FTQuest

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't have any effect.  The HSlider starts in the right place, but the item is not selected in the List. Open to any other ideas...